# How should I upgrade pip on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I want to get the most recent version (8.1.2) of pip. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.6. The version of pip in the Ubuntu repositories is only  1.5.4 (and can't install things like numpy). How are you actually meant to upgrade pip? I've discovered a few ways; maybe they're all equivalent but it would be good to know for sure.

Option 1: Upgrade pip with pip and change the link

```
apt-get install python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip --version  # still shows 1.5.4
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/
pip --version  # 8.1.2, success!
```

Option 1a: Like above, but use python -m pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip --version  # still shows 1.5.4
python -m pip --version  # 8.1.2, success!
```

Option 2: easy_install

```
easy_install -U pip
pip --version  # 8.1.2, success!
```

Option 3: Use a virtualenv (I know virtualenvs are awesome but I'm doing the installing in a docker container, so I was just going to install things globally).

```
virtualenv test123
source test123/bin/activate
pip --version  # pip 8.1.2 from ~/test123/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Option 4: The [pip website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) suggests using their get-pip.py script, but also says this might leave the Ubuntu package manager in an inconsistent state.

Option 5: Upgrade Python: "pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9", but this seems like overkill.

Is one of these the preferred method? Is there a better way I haven't found? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 5):

The most painless way that I found that works is to use install `virtualenv` and use `pip` inside a virtualenv. This does not even require you install `pip` at the system level (which you might have done by running `sudo apt-get install python-pip`):

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv  # install virtualenv
virtualenv venv  # create a virtualenv named venv
source venv/bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
pip install -U pip  # upgrade pip inside virtualenv
```

Comment: Try *not* using `apt install python-virtualenv`.  Instead, install it using `pip install virtualenv` using your system pip.  The Ubuntu virtualenv package is way out of date, and will not work as expected on many newer packages.  A newer virtualenv will give you a newer pip/wheel/setuptools, since it comes with those packaged *inside* it.   If you ever want your venvs to be up-to-date by default, use your system pip to install virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the operating system you are using the steps differ somewhat:

**On ubuntu you can do the following:**

```
sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools

sudo apt update&& sudo apt upgrade python-pip
```

**On windows:**

```
c:\>pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

**On Osx:**

```
 sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following cammands

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```